# PHP strpos and substr functions causes 'Allowed memory size exhausted' error

Tags: php, memory-leaks, substr, strpos

The part of my code is the following:

```
while( $pos1 = stripos( $description, '<style' ) ) {
  $pos2 = stripos( $description, '</style>' ) + 8;
  $description = substr( $description, 0, $pos1 ).
                 substr( $description, $pos2 );     //   <= This string causing the error
}
```

Sometimes (not all the time!) I receiving the error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 107663188 bytes) in /path/to/my/script.php on line 88

88'th line indicated by the '<=' arrow above.

The size of `$description` variable is about 100 kB's. Besides I don't see any reason to believe that this code can cause accumulation of memory allocation without to be released.

Do you see any flaws in my code?

Comment: `strpos()` isn't causing any error, it's your `substr()` that's causing the memory error. Why? Because you're creating 3 strings in memory (besides your original `$description`)... the first substr() will allocate as much additional memory as it needs to generate the first substring; the second substr() will allocate as much additional memory as it needs to generate the second substring, then the concatenate will allocate as much additional memory as it needs for the concatenated strings before assigning to $description.

Comment: @Mark, does substr function can accumulate memory allocations by its self?

Comment: don't know exactly what you mean, additional memory will be released once the line of code has been executed, but while executing that line it needs the additional memory

Comment: @Mark, but the memory ussage of each loop should be about 3 orders less than PHP tries to allocate at the moment of the fatal error.

Comment: Can you provide the original value of `$description` (not all of 100kb) and the desired output?  I'm sure there is a better way to do what you are trying.

Comment: If your $description is 100k in size, then you're basically creating two substrings totalling a little bit under 100k in size, and concatenating them takes another 100k or so.... that's 300k, plus the original 100k size of $description.... you're using nearly 400k of memory to execute that line of code

Comment: If you're manipulating HTML markup, then try using [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dom.php)

Comment: What if `</style>` is not found? `$pos2` will return `FALSE`, which will be cast as `0` and your substring keeps growing.

Comment: @Mark, can I state that after each loop the memory needed for execution of my substr function is released?

Comment: The memory required for the substr() and theconcatenation is released once that line of code has completed executing.... your problem is that it takes so much memory to execute in the first place

Comment: One more question, @Mark, if PHP informing me that it tries to allocate 100M of memory it means that this allocation was needed for the single operation and not accumulated by the previous loops?

Comment: @Bart - if `<style>` isn't found, it wont execute the code inside the while loop

Comment: Each iteration will free up memory that 300k once completed, there is no accumulation from previous loops in the code you show

Comment: @MarkBaker, but if `</style>` is not found, `$pos2` is zero, the substr returns itself and keeps growing (as `<style` is still there).

Comment: @Bart, looks like you're right (and the fellas above as well). If the HTML code is broken I CAN grow up $description up to infinity

Comment: @bart - If `<style>` is found at pos 100 (for example) but there is no `</style>` so pos2 will be 0+8 = 8, then the concatenation will be characters 0-100 . characters 8+, so you're right..... so at test that pos2 > $pos1 would be advisable - but the initial memory problems still remains

Comment: @Mark, looks like it is clear now!

Answer (score 0):

This code causes memory error

```
$description = 'hello<style></style>hello<style>';
while( $pos1 = stripos( $description, '<style' ) ) {
    $pos2 = stripos( $description, '</style>' ) + 8;
    $description = substr( $description, 0, $pos1 ).
        substr( $description, $pos2 );     //   <= This string causing the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem caused by the fact that if `</stile>` is not find - the `$description` variable will grow up to infinity.
This can appear if the `<script>` tag used in form `<script ... />`
Now the code is the following:

```
while( $pos1 = stripos( $description, '<style' ) ) {
  $pos2 = stripos( $description, '</style' ) + 8;
  if( $pos2 < $pos1 ) $pos2 = strpos( $description, '/>' ) + 2;
  if( $pos2 < $pos1 ) break 2;
  $description = substr( $description, 0, $pos1 ).
                 substr( $description, $pos2 );
}
```

Looks like there are no errors anymore...